# What is the best way to use user model in django with project from scratch

Tags: python, django, database, authentication, profile

I  have read the docs, but still confused (new with django). I need auth system with default credentials (user and password, like django default user model has) and some extra fields (like `subunit_id`, `post_id`, `role`, `parent_id`, ... etc). What kind of model do i have to use: `Proxy`, `Profile`, inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to accomplish. Do you have different user types? How many? Do you need to keep different fields for each user type?

Comment: If you have to add one or two fields you can extend default User model. If you have to use more data related to specific type (personal data, social data), you can create separate model and link it with User model.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use atleast `AbstractUser`. Don't reinvent the wheel in django

Comment: @sandeep i need to store info in more than 5 additional columns, so can't decide what to choose profile or AbstractUser. Given the fact that i start project from scratch i think the best way is to use latter?

Comment: Even in case you are creating new model, you should consider extending User model by AbstractUser. This is recommended by django official. this might help in future in your project.